# MySQL How to account for blocked users when returning comments

Tags: mysql, sql

I thought I had solved this problem, but I just realised specifying a user who is not friends with anybody in a friends table will cause that user to not be able to see any posts, this is not the behaviour I want.

A blocked user has a Category of 4. I'm aware I could return all comments from a Post and then manually check if the Category of that User is 4, but that is un-necessary computation that could be solved by a single query (I think).

```
SELECT DISTINCT
  ent.Entity_Id,
  ent.Profile_Pic_Url,
  ent.First_Name,
  ent.Last_Name,
  ent.Last_CheckIn_Place,
  comments.Content,
  friends.Category
FROM
  checkin_comments AS comments
  JOIN entity AS ent
    ON comments.Entity_Id = ent.Entity_Id
  JOIN friends 
    ON comments.Entity_Id = friends.Entity_Id1
      OR comments.Entity_Id = friends.Entity_Id2
WHERE
  comments.Chk_Id = 1726
  AND friends.Category != 4
GROUP BY comments.Comment_Id
```

This currently will return all results, because there is no way to specify the logged in user.  I then thought to supply a sub-query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
  ent.Entity_Id,
  ent.Profile_Pic_Url,
  ent.First_Name,
  ent.Last_Name,
  ent.Last_CheckIn_Place,
  comments.Content,
  friends.Category
FROM
  checkin_comments AS comments
  JOIN entity AS ent
    ON comments.Entity_Id = ent.Entity_Id
  JOIN friends 
    ON comments.Entity_Id = friends.Entity_Id1
      OR comments.Entity_Id = friends.Entity_Id2
WHERE
  comments.Chk_Id = 1726
  AND friends.Category = (
      SELECT Category FROM friends
      WHERE
        friends.Entity_Id1 = 1527
        AND friends.Entity_Id2 = comments.Entity_Id
        OR friends.Entity_Id1 = comments.Entity_Id
        AND friends.Entity_Id2 = 1527
    )
  -- filter out blocked users as they have a category of 4
  AND friends.Category != 4   
GROUP BY comments.Comment_Id
```

The idea here was to fetch the category of each user and then filter the result set based on that, this sort of worked, in the sense that it returns a list of all users who are friends, but it does not account for the use case when a comment is made by a non-friend (who won't exist in the friends table).

How can I fix this query so that all users are returned, and only users who have a Category of 4 are not shown?

If you need any more information please ask.

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for an outer join.  This variant of your first query should do the trick:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
  ent.Entity_Id,
  ent.Profile_Pic_Url,
  ent.First_Name,
  ent.Last_Name,
  ent.Last_CheckIn_Place,
  comments.Content,
  friends.Category
FROM
  checkin_comments AS comments
  JOIN entity AS ent
    ON comments.Entity_Id = ent.Entity_Id
  LEFT JOIN friends 
    ON comments.Entity_Id = friends.Entity_Id1
      OR comments.Entity_Id = friends.Entity_Id2
WHERE
  comments.Chk_Id = 1726
  AND IFNULL(friends.Category, 0) != 4
GROUP BY comments.Comment_Id
```

In the event that the comment author is not associated with the requester via the `friends` table, the comment will be included in the join result, with all columns derived from `friends` being `NULL`.  The `IFNULL()` in the `WHERE` clause deals with that by converting a `NULL` category to value `0` (though in fact any value other than `4` would work).

Comment: The reason I specify and ent.Entity_Id in the `AND` clause is to get the comments on that post for the specific logged in user.